# Cocos2d: could not launch Hellocpp

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've looked at plenty of posts with similar problems (see below), but nothing seemed to work out for me.

My cocos2d-x "HelloCpp" test app (V 2.2.5) doesn't run; it crashes right after starting it, before creating a surface, as far as I can see.

I tried to set up the Cocos2d-x test project "HelloCpp" as in [How to set up the Android Cocos2d-x development environment on Windows 7](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_set_up_the_android_cocos2d-x_development_environment_on_Windows_7) - a small difference being that I'm running on Win8.1 64bit, Eclipse Juno. I finally got to build everything without errors.

I also ran build_native.sh after some initial problems setting the NDK location. It seems to run correctly now.

The critical part of the Logcat output as far as I understand is:

> 11-10 16:08:37.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load hellocpp from loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-2,
>   /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

I understand as much as that there seems to be a problem getting the c++ libraries.

However, unlike in some of the other posts, I *do* have hellocpp.so in lib/armeabi.

Unlike here ([Cocos2D-x sample application crashes on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500867/cocos2d-x-sample-application-crashes-on-launch)), I have built the libcocos2dx project and there is the libcocos2dx.jar in the bin/res directory.

Also, I don't see anything helpful in the output when building the project, the output being:

> 19:08:36 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project
>   HelloCpp **** bash
>   C:/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh
>   NDK_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/devenv/android/android-ndk COCOS2DX_ROOT =
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..
>   APP_ROOT =
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/..
>   APP_ANDROID_ROOT =
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android
>   Using prebuilt externals
>   + /cygdrive/c/devenv/android/android-ndk/ndk-build -C /cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android
>   NDK_MODULE_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..:/cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
>   make: Entering directory
>   '/cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android'
>   Android NDK:
>   WARNING:/cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../../cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static:
>   LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries     [armeabi]
>   Install        : libhellocpp.so => libs/armeabi/libhellocpp.so make:
>   Leaving directory
>   '/cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android'
>
> 19:08:38 Build Finished (took 1s.443ms)

When I run build_native.sh in the cygwin terminal, there's no errors either.

I tried different NDKs - 10c and 9d. Result was the same.

I've run into a couple of errors due to my lack of serious programming skills, but I was able to find help in posts for all of them. This however doesn't make sense to me, since the build doesn't seem to throw errors, yet the cpp library can't be read.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: How was the result of the compilation script?

Comment: Do you mean build-native.sh? I seemed to run correctly. The only thing that caught my attention was this: "Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/c/Users/Philipp/work/fat_fishin_2/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../../cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries"

Answer (score 0):

Got help otherwise: the lib has to be built in x86 architecture, and has to be located under /libs/x86 instead of /libs/armeabi.

Some more info on that here: http://nigam.biz/cocos2dx/md___users_nigamshah__library__developer_cocos2d-x-2_81_84_tools_android-emulator-_r_e_a_d_m_e.html

Thanks!